# Repositories and getting new values for an aggregate entities / value objects

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I'm just starting out with DDD and have built a repository pattern using EF code first which so far is working very well. Now say I have an aggregate root call `Animal` which has an entity called `Status`.

Now if I need to populate a drop down list with `Status` objects, or I need to replace the `Status` object in animal with a new one. How should I access the `Status` collection. In this case `Status` is not an aggregate root and only has meaning by association with `Animal`, it will have an identity though.

Should I either create a new Repository for `Status` by making it an aggregate root (it just one of many such things so this might get out of hand), or do I allow access the `Status` collection via the `AnimalRepository` with something like `GetStatusByID` or `GetAllStatuses`?

This same question could equally apply to value objects such as color, breed, sex etc.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of stuff I'd treat as lookup/reference data; I've found this answer useful in the past: [Loading a Value object in List or DropdownList, DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478253/loading-a-value-object-in-list-or-dropdownlist-ddd/5487793#5487793)

But basically I'd have a separate repository.

Comment: Beat me too it mouters!

Here's another answer with some code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921899/simple-aggregate-root-and-repository-question/4931457#4931457